# Including department in the list of claims

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using an Azure B2C tenant to store users. At present I have to go through the graph API to retrieve the user details from my MVC application.

The annoying thing however is that the most of the details I'm interested in are already contained within the list of claims within the ClaimsPrincipal.Current object (in this case name, job title and email), so for the most part this call isn't actually needed. Department is the only one not included by default and is the only reason I'm making the call. In addition going through the graph API seems to slow things down enormously when running the site on Azure.

Is there any way of including the department in the claims list contained within the ClaimsPrincipal.Current object so I can skip the call to the graph API entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, it sounds like you are asking how to include additional claims in the ID token returned by Azure AD B2C.  The claims returned are configured on a per-policy basis.

1. Navigate to the B2C features blade on the Azure portal.
2. Click All policies.
3. Click your sign-up policy to open it. Click Edit at the top of the blade.
4. Click Application claims and select the attribute. (for example "Department") Click OK.
5. Click Sign-up attributes and make sure "Department" is one of the attributes collected from the user.
6. Click Save at the top of the blade.

Click "Run now" on the policy to verify the consumer experience.  You can use "http://jwt.ms" as the redirect URI to inspect the token returned by Azure AD B2C. You should now see "Department" in the list of attributes collected during consumer sign-up, and see it in the token sent back to your application.